# docker-compose on virtualbox machine - ./wait-for-it.sh: no such file of directory: unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox, docker-machine

I created machine:
`docker-machine create -v virtualbox docker-local`

Switched to machine: 
`eval ($docker-machine env docker-local)`

Now, Im trying to run `docker-compose` on it to serve my apps on this machine.

This are my files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: db
        ports:
          - '3306:3306'
        environment:
           MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'asdasd123'
        command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']

    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/python/Dockerfile
        container_name: app
        volumes: 
            - ./app:/app
            - static:/app/static
            - media:/app/media
        command: >
            ./wait-for-it.sh db:3306 --timeout=30 --strict -- ./run.sh
        expose:
            - "8000"
        depends_on:
            - db

    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/nginx/Dockerfile
        volumes: 
            - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./nginx_logs:/var/log/nginx
            - ./nginx_html:/html
            - ./ssl_cert:/etc/nginx/conf.d/certs/
            - static:/static
            - media:/media
        ports: 
            - "1337:80"
            - "443:443"
        depends_on: 
            - app

volumes: 
    static:
    media:
```

If i lauch this docker-compose.yml using `docker-compose up` everything **works fine in local pc**, however on virtualbox machine -  error accured:

```
Creating db ... done
Creating app ... error

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"./wait-for-it.sh\": stat ./wait-for-it.sh: no such file or directory": unknown

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"./wait-for-it.sh\": stat ./wait-for-it.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Why is this happening only on docker-machine? Why it has no access to wait-for-it.sh here?

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile for the python project? When you run in local, if you only run docker-compose up, you might be using an old image. You should use the --build flag to make sure that your image is up to date. In the VM there is no image so the build process kicks in automatically.

Comment: All of those `volumes:` can cause inconsistent behavior between environments too: you're running whatever the host has in `./app`, plus an older version of the `static` and `media` content.  Does deleting those help, or at least give you consistent behavior between the two setups?